# Latest Facebook Graph API changes and image uploads

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, air

I have an Adobe AIR kiosk based (multiple users)application that requires Facebook image upload functionality. This was achievable before by forcing a logout after each image upload.

But now Facebook's latest SDK uses a Safari view for login:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/

so I don't think this is possible.
Can anyone confirm this? For kiosk based(multiple-user) applications that require Facebook image uploads, what are the options now?

Comment: Use Device Login instead

Comment: _“kiosk based(multiple-user) applications”_ are a bad idea for FB apps anyway. Highly likely that Facebook’s security algorithms will identify multiple logins from a single device, over a short period of time, as suspicious activity – and that can lead to added hassle for users (having to confirm their identify via an extra steps, such as identifying friends on profile pictures), up to a blocking o your app.